# Install of Mythbuntu steps docs

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

Is there a written (TXT) step by step on install of Mythbuntu that a newbie can follow easily?

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://www.mythtvbook.com/wiki/The_Easy_Way:_Installing_MythBuntu), it might help.

Comment: close voters: Mythbuntu is an official ubuntu derivative and thus **is not** off-topic here.